# Простое глагольное сказуемое

Tags: синтаксис

> **Давайте помечтаем**, например, о той жизни, какая будет после нас, лет через двести-триста.

Это ПГС, выраженное сложной формой будущего времени? Если это не ПГС, то что?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простое глагольное сказуемое может включать в свой состав модальные частицы со значением побудительности: **пусть** он уйдет, **давайте** пообедаем.

Эти частицы используются для образования **повелительного наклонения** (побуждение к действию) при сочетании с глаголом в форме 3-го лица  или 1-го лица будущего времени.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это простое глагольное сказуемое, выраженное модальным словом с глаголом.